# Mapping an arrays values to another array

Tags: java, arrays, mapping

I have this 2d array called `input` and I am trying to map different numbers in another array to change it. In the 2d array `mapping` it contains all the mappings I want to perform.The first array is `{0,2,3,4,1,5}` and I want to use this to change the values in  `input` so every 1 becomes a 2, and 2 to 3 and 3 to 4 and 4 to 1. I have 23 different mappings in that mapping array which I would want to change the values of `input`. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
 public static int [][] mapOrientation(int input[][]){
    int [][] input = {{0,0,0,5},{4,1,1,4},{2,2,0,2},{1,2,3,5},{3,3,3,4},{1,5,5,4}};

     int[][] mapping ={{0,2,3,4,1,5},{1,2,0,4,5,3},{5,2,1,4,3,0},{3,2,5,4,0,1},
                       {3,5,4,0,2,1},{2,5,3,0,1,4},{1,5,2,0,4,3},{4,5,1,0,3,2},
                       {4,1,0,3,5,2},{5,1,4,3,2,0},{2,1,5,3,0,4},{0,1,2,3,4,5},
                       {0,4,1,2,3,5},{3,4,0,2,5,1},{5,4,3,2,1,0},{1,4,5,2,0,3},
                       {1,0,4,5,2,3},{2,0,1,5,3,4},{3,0,2,5,4,1},{4,0,3,5,1,2},
                       {4,1,0,3,5,2},{5,1,4,3,2,0},{2,1,5,3,0,4}};

    int [] comb = mapping[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++){

            input[i][j] = comb[0];
            System.out.println(comb[0]);
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(input));

   cubeToString = Arrays.deepToString(input);

    return input;
}
```

If this is still unclear my goal is to change `input` from

```
int [][] input ={{5,1,2,0},{2,0,1,4},{1,2,5,5},{3,0,1,3},{4,3,0,4},{3,2,5,4}}
```

to:

```
int [][] input ={{5,2,3,0},{3,0,2,1},{2,3,5,5},{4,0,2,4},{1,4,0,1},{4,3,5,1}}
```

This would be the result I want using `comb[0]`.

Comment: why are the mapping arrays bigger than the input arrays? i'm confused... is the result you want based on using the mapping[0][0] on input and the result would be in comb[0]?

Comment: because the mapping arrays contain the combination of mappings of which I would like to use to modify `input` so I use `comb[0]` to access the first mapping array @RAZ_Muh_Taz

Comment: What do you mean by `the mapping arrays contain the combination of mappings`? how  does it work ?

Comment: No `0 -> 0, 1-> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1` is the first combination. @Michael

Comment: Is the number of inputs aqual to the number of the mappings or you just want to implement one mapping to all the inputs?

Comment: I want to implement all mapping to inputs but I want to get at least one working. @TiMr

Comment: Right, so using a value to **index into** any mapping array will give you the value which should be substituted.

Comment: yes that is correct. Here is a table which may help it make more sense. 

     `Original mapping :012345
     First mapping       023415`

Note not all the numbers changed in the first mapping if you can tell from the end of the post the original input 5's and 0's stayed in the same area. @Michael

Comment: is this `0 -> 0, 1-> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1` always the case you apply to `input`?

Comment: Not always, as it is just the first array in mapping . The rest of the arrays in follow their own pattern. @Null

Comment: Can't you provide a sample to describe how did you get those result by applying this array `{0,2,3,4,1,5}` as a filter ?

Comment: If you look at the end of my post I show an example of the mapping we are talking about the first input is the original and the second one is the one that gets mapped. @Michael

Comment: If the index of input element is equivalent to the value of input element then get the corresponding value from the mapping, Am I right?

Comment: @Null I have an array of mappings, I would want to use those mappings to change the values of the input array. Only some values should change based on the mapping called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
 input[i][j] = comb[0];
```

You are setting the value to always equal the first item of the mapping. What you actually want is

```
 input[i][j] = comb[input[i][j]];
```

---

**Runnable example**

```
public class NewClass
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        int[][] input = {{5,1,2,0},{2,0,1,4},{1,2,5,5},{3,0,1,3},{4,3,0,4},{3,2,5,4}};
        mapOrientation(input);
    }

    public static int [][] mapOrientation(int input[][])
    {
        int[][] mappings ={{0,2,3,4,1,5},{1,2,0,4,5,3},{5,2,1,4,3,0},{3,2,5,4,0,1},
                           {3,5,4,0,2,1},{2,5,3,0,1,4},{1,5,2,0,4,3},{4,5,1,0,3,2},
                           {4,1,0,3,5,2},{5,1,4,3,2,0},{2,1,5,3,0,4},{0,1,2,3,4,5},
                           {0,4,1,2,3,5},{3,4,0,2,5,1},{5,4,3,2,1,0},{1,4,5,2,0,3},
                           {1,0,4,5,2,3},{2,0,1,5,3,4},{3,0,2,5,4,1},{4,0,3,5,1,2},
                           {4,1,0,3,5,2},{5,1,4,3,2,0},{2,1,5,3,0,4}};

        System.out.println("Before");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(input));

        int[] mapping = mappings[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++)
            {
                input[i][j] = mapping[input[i][j]];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("After");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(input));

        //cubeToString = Arrays.deepToString(input);

        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try doing that as well but it wouldn't  change the values of input.

Comment: I've tested it and it matches your expected results. I've edited in a runnable example to my answer.